# Is there any library available to iterate xml documents as dynamic objects

Tags: xml, dynamic, linq-to-xml

In my current **ASP.NET MVC** project the model appears as **XML**, so from the controller to the view I pass the model as **XElement**. In the view I use **XLinq** to iterate the xml and display the things out.

I've found this nice post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/10/19/dynamic-in-c-4-0-creating-wrappers-with-dynamicobject.aspx that says about creating dynamic wrappers around xml objects.

I just want to know that is there any library out there that simplifies this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can check out this one: http://www.amazedsaint.com/2010/02/introducing-elasticobject-for-net-40.html that can make a dynamic object from a XElement and vice-versa. Is a nice implementation this ElasticObject. I have been used myself.